# Instantiate a module based on a condition in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a 1023 bit vector in Verilog. All I want to do is check if the ith bit is 1 and if it is 1 , I have to add 'i' to another variable .

In C , it would be something like :

```
int sum=0;
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<1023;i++) {
if(a[i]==1) {
sum=sum+i;
}
```

Of course , the addition that I am doing is over a Galois Field . So, I have a module called Galois_Field_Adder to do the computation .
So, my question now is how do I conditionally check if a specific bit is 1 and if so call my module to do that specific addition .

NOTE: The 1023 bit vector is declared as an input .

Comment: What have you tried? Please show the full module. FYI: you do not call modules; you instantiate them. For what you are trying to do, instantiate modules will make things more complicated. Just create one module with one combinational always block.

Comment: By "called" I meant that the module name is Galois_field_adder. I know that we instantiate modules . Thanks for the input though .

Comment: You still haven't showed us your attemnt or tell us how you plan implement it. Do you want 1023 instantiations of Galosis_field_adder? Or one instance of the adder with the equations solved in 1023 clocks?

Comment: the check could be done in a very similar way as you do in 'c'. However verilog requires you to take in consideration multiple aspects of hardware design and/or test bench design. So,  you cannot just put it in a module. You would need to put it in a specific verilog primitives and probably consider use of clocks and resets. So, do study verilog and try to create your first verilog model.

Comment: Well, I can instantiate a module conditionally using the conditional generate statement .  The only problem with that is that 'a' is not an fixed variable . It is not known until runtime . I know ways to do it but I was looking for better solutions . FYI I have had two courses in Verilog and you can go look up conditional generate if in case you forgot how it works,

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question without seeing your module, as we can't gage where you are in your Verilog. You always have to think of how your code translates in gates. If we want to translate your C code into synthesizable logic, we can take the same algorithm, go through each bit one after the other, and add to the sum depending on each bit. You would use something like this:

```
module gallois (
  input   wire            clk,
  input   wire            rst,
  input   wire  [1022:0]  a,
  input   wire            a_valid,
  output  reg   [18:0]    sum,
  output  reg             sum_valid
);

reg [9:0]    cnt;
reg [1021:0] shift_a;

always @(posedge clk)
if (rst)
begin
  sum[18:0] <= {19{1'bx}};
  sum_valid <= 1'b0;
  cnt[9:0] <= 10'd0;
  shift_a[1021:0] <= {1022{1'bx}};
end
else
  if (a_valid)
  begin
    sum[18:0] <= 19'd0;
    sum_valid <= 1'b0;
    cnt[9:0] <= 10'd1;
    shift_a[1021:0] <= a[1022:1];
  end
  else if (cnt[9:0])
  begin
    if (cnt[9:0] == 10'd1022)
    begin
      sum_valid <= 1'b1;
      cnt[9:0] <= 10'd0;
    end
    else
      cnt[9:0] <= cnt[9:0] + 10'd1;

    if (shift_a[0])
      sum[18:0] <= sum[18:0] + cnt[9:0];

    shift_a[1021:0] <= {1'bx, shift_a[1021:1]};
  end

endmodule
```

You will get your result after 1023 clock cycles. This code needs to be modified depending on what goes around it, what interface you want etc...
Of importance here is that we use a shift register to test each bit, so that the logic adding your sum only takes shift_a[0], sum and cnt as an input.
Code based on the following would also work in simulation:

```
if (a[cnt[9:0])
  sum[18:0] <= sum[18:0] + cnt[9:0];
```

but the logic adding to sum would in effect take all 1023 bits of a[] as an input. This would be quite hard to turn into actual lookup tables.

In simulation, you can also implement something very crude such as this:

```
reg   [1022:0]a;
reg   [9:0] sum;
integer i;

always @(a)
begin
  sum[9:0] = 10'd0;
  for (i=0; i < 1023; i=i+1)
    if (a[i])
      sum[9:0] = sum[9:0] + i;
end
```

If you were to try to synthesize this, sum would actually turn into a chunk of combinatorial logic, as the 'always' block doesn't rely on a clock. This code is in fact equivalent to this:

```
always @(a)
  case(a):
    1023'd0: sum[18:0] = 19'd0;
    1023'd1: sum[18:0] = 19'd1;
    1023'd2: sum[18:0] = 19'd3;
    etc...
```

Needless to say that a lookup table with 1023 input bits is a VERY big memory...

Then if you want to improve your code, and use your FPGA as an FPGA and not like a CPU, you need to start thinking about parallelism, for instance working in parallel on different ranges of your input a. But this is another thread...

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable insight . I really really appreciate it

Comment: No problem, make sure to accept the solution or upvote it if it helped you :-)